# Classification system for data (have data accessible by several keywords)

Tags: elisp

I want to create a library of useful info.

I want to be able to have each info-snippet classified by several keywords

I.e.

`("Jumping Flame Spiders go for your face. Get your pet cat to eat them.")`

could be classified with the keywords `spiders`, `everyday-tips-and-tricks` and `cats`.

Later, all searches for any of the combinations of the keywords above should return the line above and all other relevant ones.

Is this possible to do in emacs lisp? Which libraries should I look into? If I have to "shell out", what would be the most multiple-platform friendly way of doing it?

Edit: my main use case will be to provide one piece of info (a paragraph of two) in the mode line or displayed in a buffer. If many info pieces match, I'll select one randomly.

Comment: Better title appreciated. Such a system/structure might have a specific name in elisp.

Comment: Depends on the scale of a project, but I'd go with http://whitedb.org (it has Python bindings, which can be then used via Pymacs). Graph databases are best for modelling this kind of data. I've heard about Emacs moving towards CFFI of its own, but I've not experimented with it yet, but if that's a reality rather than a wishful thinking, then I'd try to write Elisp bindings for this or similar database (I've started it once in CL, and the API is rather small).

Comment: @wvxvw Looks neat, thanks for the tip. It does have the drawback that all users will need to dl a separate program though, but I'll keep it in mind. They do not seem to have a simple install procedure a la brew or sudo apt-get though....

Comment: I didn't have problems compiling their code. The project seems to be well-maintained. But there certainly are alternative, more established solutions: SQLite (has ELisp libraries) or BerkleyDB (more robust / can be used to implement a graph database on top of it). There are also popular, simpler to manage ones, like Mongo or Redis / Tokyo Cabinet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Put your wisdom in a file or files.
2. Bookmark those locations.
3. Load library [**Bookmark+**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus).
4. [**Tag**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus#BookmarkTags) your bookmarks with whatever keywords you like.

   Tags are *arbitrary strings* - not limited to words or symbols.  You can also tag a bookmark when you create it (i.e., be prompted automatically to add tags).
5. Use any combination of tags when you jump to a bookmark.

   The bookmark candidates are filtered by the tags you specify.

Comment: Since I want to display one wisdom at a time in the mode line or a separate buffer (chosen at random if several are applicable, I guess I will need to write some additional code for this. But thanks, I will look into it.

Comment: I hope to create a package of this eventually. Will the bookmarks be simple to transfer/install on other machines? I guess having the user point to a base folder in their dotfile should work...

Comment: You need Bookmark+ to use bookmarks with tags. That's the only requirement - you can use them on any machine/platform. And bookmarks can point to remote files.